# How would one make a point move along a hyperbolic trajectory?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's take the equation $y^2 - x^2 = 1$, for example. How would one create an equation that makes a point follow one of the hyperbola's curves?

Comment: This can be written as $y=\pm\sqrt{x^2+1}$. Pick one curve (either $+$ or $-$), and let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ trace your curve via the map $f(x)=(x,\sqrt{x^2+1})$ or $f(x)=(x,-\sqrt{x^2+1})$

Comment: You can also use the hyperbolic functions: $$(x,y)=\left(\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}2,\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}2\right),\ -\infty<t<\infty$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Parametric_equations